# How to write publisher that conditionally publish?

Tags: swift, combine

Lets say I have a publisher like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSNotification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange)
  .map { notification in /.. do something ../}
```

how do I make it so that in my block, I stop the publisher from emitting?

I could make it a trymap and then throw an error. But it's so weird to have to throw just to indicate a lack of results (in this case, let's say a non relevant NSManagedObject change)

Comment: You could use `compactMap` and return `nil` when you don't want to emit a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use the `filter` operator. This passes the original input downstream if the predicate is true:

```
NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange)
  .filter { note in note.object === myContext }
  .map { note in /.. do something ../}
```

Another way (mentioned by bscothern in a comment) is to use `compactMap`. You can transform the input into a different output, or into nil if want to suppress output:

```
NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange)
  .compactMap { note in note.object === myContext ? myContext : nil }
  .map { context in /.. do something ../}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is possible approach based on connectable publisher (the demo is based on SwiftUI). Tested with Xcode 11.3.1 / iOS 13.3

[image: demo]

```
struct TestConnectableNotification: View {

    let publisher = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: Notification.Name("test")).makeConnectable()

    @State private var text = "<none>"
    @State private var subscriber: Cancellable? = nil
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Current: \(text)")
                .onReceive(publisher) { _ in
                    let value = Int.random(in: 0..<10)
                    self.text = "\(value)"
                }
            Button(self.subscriber == nil ? "Enable" : "Disable") {
                if nil == self.subscriber {
                    self.subscriber = self.publisher.connect()
                } else {
                    self.subscriber?.cancel()
                    self.subscriber = nil
                }
            }
            Button("Post") {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("test"), object: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `flatMap` and emit an Empty as the blocker (and a Just otherwise):

```
NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange)
    .flatMap { input -> AnyPublisher<Notification, Never> in
        if somethingOrOther {
            return Just(input).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        } else {
            return Empty().eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the advantage of flapmap in this case over compactmap with nils?

Comment: I didn't say there was an advantage.

Comment: Im just curious what the tradeoffs are between the two approaches

Comment: `flatMap` is more powerful than `compactMap`. For example, `flatMap` can replace a single input with any number of outputs, but `compactMap` can only replace an input with zero or one outputs. However, `flatMap` is also more complicated to use and more expensive at runtime than `compactMap`.